# How to create fiddles for Sencha touch 2.1.1 or 2.2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-touch-2.2

Since fiddles are very useful to explain and understand issues on any forum I would like to create fiddle for Sencha touch 2.1.1(which is the version I use) when I post here but http://www.senchafiddle.com/ only oppers Sencha-Touch-2.0.1 and http://jsfiddle.net/ doesn't even have any option for Sencha Touch, so how to make fiddles with latest versions?

Comment: http://new.senchafiddle.com uses 2.1.0 if it can help you

Comment: Great! Please add it as answer so that I can mark it accepted.

Comment: Why -ive vote, please explain so that I can keep it in mind for future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have access to Sencha Touch 2.1 with [New Senchafiddle](http://new.senchafiddle.com)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [sencha playground](http://sencha.walkingtree.in/playground/) by [WalkingTree](http://walkingtree.in/). I haven't played with it much but it seems legit.

Comment: That's good but it doesn't save your code and give unique URL to be shared on forums

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle will work. Just need to specifiy the external resources. Sometimes SenchaFiddle gives me errors when I try to save my code. This is an alternative in case senchafiddle doesn't behave as expected.

Sencha CDN will have the required css and js files.

Eg. 2.2.1 css and js url

```
http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/sencha-touch-all-debug.js
http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/resources/css/sencha-touch.css
```

Other versions can be accessed like

```
http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.1/resources/css/sencha-touch.css
http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.1/sencha-touch-all-debug.js
```

Then I put everything I need inside the launch function in the code below.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    launch: function () {
        //Your code goes here.
    }
});
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/blessenm/6rse9/).

Answer (score 1):

The official Sencha Touch Fiddle now seems to be live:

[fiddle.sencha.com](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home)

The other fiddle site (new.senchafiddle.com), marked at the answer above, no longer seems to be up and running.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working anymore as well. Not working for me, at least. The [Sencha Playground](http://sencha.walkingtree.in/playground/) works here.

Comment: [fiddle.sencha.com](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home) is still up and running and is the official Sencha fiddle site